# Display nested object in column in primeng

Tags: javascript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am following the templating option given in primeng docs to create a link with column data alongside in a primeng datatable column, but I am not able to show nested object using {{data[col.field]}}.

```js
<p-column [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [sortable]="col.sortable" [filter]="col.filter" [editable]="col.editable" [filterPlaceholder]="col.filterPlaceholder" styleClass="{{col.class}}">
                <ng-template let-col let-data="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
                    <span *ngIf="!col.field.includes('.')" >{{data[col.field]}}</span>
                    <!-- <span *ngIf="col.field.includes('.')">{{data[col.field.split('.')[0]][col.field.split('.')[1]]}}</span> this does not work because field is like x.y-->
                    <!-- I have some other buttons here as well --> 
                </ng-template>
        </p-column>
```

How can I acheive this?

Sharing entire code -->

```js
<p-dataTable [globalFilter]="gb" [filterDelay]=1000 [value]="tableData" [alwaysShowPaginator]="true" [rowStyleClass]="setStyle" [rows]="rows" [paginator]="paginate" [alwaysShowPaginator]="false" [resizableColumns]="true" tableStyleClass="table-wrap {{rowClass}}"
    [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]" expandableRows="{{setExpander}}" [editable]="setEditable" (onRowClick)="handleRowSelect($event)" [lazy]="pagination" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" (onLazyLoad)="loadLazy($event)" [ngClass]="{'paginator-table': pagination}">
    <div *ngFor="let col of tableOptions.columns, let index=index, let odd=odd, let even=even">
        <p-column *ngIf="col.field" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [sortable]="col.sortable" [filter]="col.filter" [editable]="col.editable" [filterPlaceholder]="col.filterPlaceholder" styleClass="{{col.class}}">
            <ng-template let-col let-data="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
                    <span *ngIf="!col.field.includes('.')" >{{data[col.field]}}</span>
                    <!-- <span *ngIf="col.field.includes('.')">{{data[col.field.split('.')[0]][col.field.split('.')[1]]}}</span> this does not work because field is like x.y-->
                <a *ngIf="col.field === 'ticket'" target="_blank" href={{link}}{{data[col.field]}}><i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </ng-template>
        </p-column>
    </div>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: Can you share the entire `p-datatable` html code and the typescript which goes with it please ? Or even better, create a Plunker ? Also, you should remove the square brackets of the `field` property.

Comment: If I make it a flat object everything works fine but how can I make it work for nested object.

Comment: Can you share the relevant typescript code please ?

Comment: I am following same code like example here but the data I get from backend is a  nested obj for some fields. For nested obj, we can write car.color etc right?

Answer (score 22):

PrimeNG DataTable is deprecated, use Table (AKA TurboTable) instead. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5-2-0-rc1-released-turbotable/

Anyways, you could access nested object inside Data-Table as follows:

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="data" ... >
  ...
  // Definition of table body
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
         <div *ngIf="col.subfield;then nested_object_content else normal_content"></div>
         <ng-template #nested_object_content>
           {{rowData[col.field][col.subfield]}}
         </ng-template>
         <ng-template #normal_content>
           {{rowData[col.field]}}
         </ng-template>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ngTemplate>
  ...
</p-table>
```

and in your component:

```
public data = [
{
  field1: {
    subfield1: 'test'
  },
  field2: 'test',
  field3: 'test',
  field4: {
    subfield4: 'test'
  }
}]

this.cols = [
  { field: 'field1', subfield: 'subfield1'},
  { field: 'field2'},
  { field: 'field3'},
  { field: 'field4', subfield: 'subfield4'},
];
```

I hope this helps you. :)

Comment: and what about sorting of that subfield?

Comment: @Harsh did you find an answer?

Answer (score 9):

As a follow-up to what Bandeeta said about TurboTable: this solution can handle multiple nested properties instead of just one subfield:

```
<tr [pSelectableRow]="row">
  <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
    <span>{{ getCellData(row, col) }}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And in your component:

```
getCellData(row: any, col: any): any {
   const nestedProperties: string[] = col.field.split('.');
   let value: any = row;
   for (const prop of nestedProperties) {
     value = value[prop];
   }

   return value;
 }
```

Comment: Nice... Just to avoid null reference access, you can replace with 
>> value = value ? value[prop] : ''; << inside for loop.

Comment: yes but this won't work for editable binding (ie. ngModel)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using Angular Custom Pipe. Sample here.

app.component.html

```html
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{rowData|field:col}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  cars = [
    {
      year: 2019,
      brand: {
        name: "Toyota"
      },
      color: "White",
      passengers: [
        {
          name: "John"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      year: 2018,
      brand: {
        name: "Toyota"
      },
      color: "White",
      passengers: [
        {
          name: "Suzanne"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      year: 2017,
      brand: {
        name: "Toyota"
      },
      color: "White",
      passengers: [
        {
          name: "Gökhan"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  cols: any[];
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cols = [
      { field: "year", header: "Year" },
      { field: "brand.name", header: "Brand" },
      { field: "color", header: "Color" },
      { field: "passengers.0.name", header: "Passengers" }
    ];
  }
}
```

Running example is here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-qhxptl

Comment: Worked like a charm, the stackblitz demo was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @gkhnclk for a simple solution

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article on how to do this in a type safe way [here](https://codewithstyle.info/Deep-property-access-in-TypeScript/) but if safety isn't an issue, you can use Lodash' `get` function which saves having to deviate from the PrimeNG basic table use with crazy subfield stuff.

```
// in .ts file
import {get} from 'lodash';

// give it a different name if you like
_ = get;

// columns
this.columns = [
    {field: 'user.address.postcode', header: 'Post Code'}
]
```

Then in the html

```
<p-table [columns]="columns" [value]="users$ | async" styleClass="p- 
datatable-sm">
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
<tr>
  <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
    {{col.header}}
  </th>
</tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
<tr>
  <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
    {{_(rowData, col.field)}}
  </td>
</tr>
</ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little bit late, but I ended up with a bit different solution. I have my own table component based on p-table and I bind the columns, rows, etc.

I created a component specifically for this, then I bind the current row and column

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
          <app-table-column [column]="col" [row]="rowData"></app-table-column>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

This is my table-column component, I'm sharing a very basic stuff but you can improve it as you wish/need.

I'm using lodash to get the row's value based on the field (column), it works for dotted (nested properties) or for flat properties.

```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Component({
  template: `
    <span>
      {{ value }}
    </span>
  `,
  selector: 'app-table-column',
})
export class TableColumnComponent implements OnInit{

  @Input() column;
  @Input() row;

  value: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.parseValue(_.get(this.row, this.column.field));
  }

  parseValue(value) {
    switch (this.column.type) {
      case 'date':
        this.value = moment(value);
        break;

      default:
        this.value = value;
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.cols = [
      { field: 'value1', header: 'Value 1' },
      { field: 'value2', header: 'Value 2', element: true },
    ];
```

```html
<td class="" *ngFor="let col of columns">
  <span class="ui-column-title">{{ col.header }} : </span>
  {{col.element ? rowData[col.field].label : rowData[col.field]}}
</td>
```